# How to Suppress Linefeed Using str.format

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I know how to use `end=""` with the `print` function in Python 3.0 to suppress a linefeed, but how do I suppress a linefeed while using the `str.format` method?

```
print("Hello", end=",") # Works
print(" Hola")
print("{}".format(""))
print("{}".format("Hello", end = ",")) # Doesn't work
print("{}".format(" Hola"))
```

Comment: You might want to provide more information on the issue (and possibly more details in each of the examples) in order to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newline is being added by the `print` function, not `str.format`.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> Print `objects` to the text stream `file`, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`.

Notice how the `end` parameter defaults to `'\n'` (a newline). There is no way for `str.format` to remove this newline because it isn't there until *after* the formatted string is given to `print`.

You will need to use `end=""`:

```
print("{}".format("Hello"), end="")
```

Comment: Superb. You would not believe how many ways I tried this before subjecting myself to the notorious moderators here. This may be the only combination I did not try.Thanks.